# How to Extract Each Component in Array using Hive

Tags: sql, hive

I have dataset like below in Hive. How can I pull out each component in the "Answer" column without using LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(Answer) which extracts the outcome in each row? I want the outcome to be in one row. I use HIVE SQL.

```
dataset:
    id   | Answer
    -----| ----------
    123  | ["A","B","C","D","E"]
    456  | ["A","B","C","E"]
    789  | ["A","B","C"]


Expected outcome: 
    id   | Answer
    -----| ----------
    123  | "A","B","C","D","E"
    456  | "A","B","C","E"
    789  | "A","B","C"
```

Comment: how is the column Answer defined? array or string?

Comment: According to Hive, it was defined as array<string>

Comment: if it is a string then just remove [] by substring function, isn't?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were asking about the expected outcome. The Answer column is array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`concat_ws`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions).

```
select id,concat_ws(',',answer)
from tbl
```